# What parameter is necessary for the AIC criterion applied to linear regression models?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, maximum-likelihood, linear-regression, log-likelihood

I did a linear regression model (OLS) and a spatial autoregressive model (Spatial lag). I read that for comparing these models I need to use the Akaike information criterion (AIC). The formula is the following
$$
AIC=-2log L(\hat\theta)+2k
$$
where $\theta$ is the vector of model parameters, $L(\hat\theta)$ is the likelihood of the candidate model given the data when evaluated at the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$ and $k$ is the number of estimated parameters in the candidate model.

But I don't understand what parameters $\theta$ are necessary to use AIC in a linear regression context. For example, if I have a model like this $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+...+\beta_nX_n+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a normal variable with zero mean and variance $\sigma$ How do I calculate its AIC?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters $\theta$ are anything you need to estimate in your model. In the case of OLS, it would be the regression coefficients $\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_n$, so you have $k=n+1$.

The log likelihood for OLS is simply the quadratic function that comes from the Gaussian-nkise assumption:
$$\log L(\theta) = -\frac{N}{2}\log \sigma^2-\sum_{k=1}^N -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}( y_k -\beta_0-\beta_1 x_{k,1} -\cdots -\beta_n x_{k,n})^2 .$$

Comment: Yea, but $L(\hat \theta)$ is a real number, for example, here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093369/bayesian-information-criterion-derivation-for-linear-regression he or she took the derivate of $L$ with respect to $\sigma$  (I don't know why ) and then evaluated that value in  $L$  to obtain $L(\hat \theta)$

Comment: That is if $\sigma$ is unknown; then you maximize the likelihood with respect to it to find the maximum likelihood estimate. It's clear that $L(\hat \theta)$ is a real number: adding $k$ to it you get the $AIC$, which is itself a real number.

Comment: So, to apply the AIC to a linear regression I have to assume that $Y$ are iid with normal distribution to get its likelihood function, right?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is normal and $X$ are given, then $Y$ is necessarily normal :) but yes, the likelihood function is based on some assumption on the distribution of the observations (in this case, normal).

Comment: Great!! I have understood everything thank you very much.